# wrong mysql output

Tags: mysql

if I have these two tables :

Table1

```
AID1____________FID____________value1

1------------1----------12

7------------2-----------1

8------------1-----------1
```

Table2

```
AID2____________FID____________value2

7------------1----------3.3
```

When I execute the following query :

```
Select table1.value1, table2.value2, table1.AID1, table2.AID2

from table1,table2

where table1.FID = 1 or table2.FID = 1
```

I get :

```
value1_____________Value2_____AID1______AID2

12----------------- 3.3--------1--------7

1------------------3.3---------7--------7

1------------------3.3---------8---------7
```

But this is not the desired output, because some values should be NULL, but what I get is values doubled !
Can anyone help ?

This is my desired output :
 value1_***_*____***Value2***_*AID1*__**_AID2

```
12----------------- 3.3--------1--------7

1------------------NULL---------7--------NULL

1------------------NULL---------8---------NULL
```

Comment: you forgot to join the tables

Comment: The result set is not clear. Explain what result should be retrieved.

Comment: for example, why is 3.3 displayed three times, can't I have it just once ( in the first row only) , and in all the other rows set to NULL ? its because I only have it once in Table2

Comment: Well what IS the output you expect? Do you want a JOIN, an OUTER JOIN, a UNION?

Comment: what im saying is that I dnt want entries t be repeated , could this be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to

```
Select table1.value1, table2.value2, table1.AID1, table2.AID2

from table1,table2

where table1.FID = 1 AND table2.FID = 1
```

Comment: This will give cartesian production, not what the OP expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the scenario you describe and it is working as expected.

**Table1:**

```
AID1 -> int
FID -> int
value1 -> float
```

**Table2:**

```
AID2 -> int
FID -> int
value2 -> float
```

**result:**

```
value1, value2, AID1, AID2
12,3.3,1,7
1,3.3,7,7
1,3.3,8,7
NULL,3.3,NULL,7
```

How are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a union.

Select table1.value1, table1.AID1,
from table1
where table1.FID = 1

union

Select table2.value2, table2.AID2
from table2
where  table2.FID = 1